# how to make time cooldown within 1min and restart again

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have my code like this and after refresh it should be running

```
<?php 
$dt = new DateTime;
$dt->setTime(0, 0);
echo $dt->format('H:i:s');

$dt->add(new DateInterval('PT1M'));
echo $dt->format('H:i:s');

//00:00:00 
//00:01:00


?>
```

How do I make 1min cool down like this output?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to reload the page after a minute. For this purpose you can add a script which does that:

```
<?php 
$dt = new DateTime;
$dt->setTime(0, 0);
echo $dt->format('H:i:s');

$dt->add(new DateInterval('PT1M'));
echo $dt->format('H:i:s');

//00:00:00 
//00:01:00


?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.href = window.location.href;
    }, 1000);

</script>
```

You can achieve this via polling as well, sending AJAX requests if you want to avoid full page reload.